# Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: Ruta (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling:

Tags: base-de-datos, flutter, server, sqflite

Estoy haciendo una app en flutter, en este momento estoy tratando de hacer una sincronización local, la DB local esta creada con sqflite y no cuenta con ningún dato solo se crea la tabla rutas y lo que necesito es que se sincronice con los datos del servidor externo, la DB local tiene que guardar los datos que vienen del servidor externo, con la petición post que implemento, si recibo respuesta del servidor, pero cuando intento implementar el código para sincronizar y guardar los datos en la DB local arroja un error, se crea la DB al momento de hacer click en el botón de sincronizar, pero arroja el siguiente error:

```
I/flutter ( 4363): /data/user/0/com.example.xicaras_app/app_flutter/XicarasDB.db
I/flutter ( 4363): Tabla creada
E/SQLiteLog( 4363): (1)
E/flutter ( 4363): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: DatabaseException(no such table: Ruta (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Ruta (usu_ruta, id_cte, nom_cte, tipo_ruta, bonif_cte, ubicacion) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)) sql 'INSERT INTO Ruta (usu_ruta, id_cte, nom_cte, tipo_ruta, bonif_cte, ubicacion) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [1, 3, Prueba 2, Visita, 2.00, dsv]}
```

código de mi Db:

```
class DBXicaras {

  static Database _database;

  static final DBXicaras db = DBXicaras._();

  DBXicaras._();

  Future<Database> get database async {

    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;

  }

  Future<Database> initDB() async {

    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'XicarasDB.db');
    print(path);

    //crear DB
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onOpen: (db) {},
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );

  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {

    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE rutas(
        id_ruta INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        usu_ruta INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
        id_cte INTEGER(11) NOT NULL,
        nom_cte VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        tipo_ruta VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
        bonif_cte VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
        ubicacion VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
      )''');
    print('Tabla creada');

  }


  Future<int> newRuta(RutaModel newRuta) async {

    final db = await database;
    final resp = await db.insert("Ruta", newRuta.toJson());
    print(resp);
    print('se guardo correctamente');
    return resp;
    
  }
```

Mi código para hacer la petición al servidor y la sincronización es el siguiente:

```
class RutaProvider {
  
  Future getRoute() async {
    
    final _prefs = new UserPreferences();

    var data;

    final url =
        'https://ba1118c.online-server.cloud/xicaras/config_mb_res/res_rutas_user.php';

    final resp = await http.post(url, body: {
      'ruta_user': _prefs.iduser.toString(),
      'parents': 'eHdNMStObFdVVXlsWlYwSERDcVlSUmsvbG40cHNqVk5DdnF3NWJFTmdiaz0='
    });

    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      data = json.decode(resp.body);

      for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        await DBXicaras.db.newRuta(new RutaModel(
            usuRuta: int.parse(data[i]["ruta_user"]),
            // idRuta: int.parse(data[i]["id"]),
            idCte: int.parse(data[i]["id_cte"]),
            nomCte: data[i]["nombre_cte"],
            // statusRuta: data[i]["status_ruta"],
            // fechaRuta: data[i]["ubicacion"],
            tipoRuta: data[i]["tipo"],
            bonifCte: data[i]["bonificacion"],
            // porcientoBonif: data[i]["porciento_bonif"],
            ubicacion: data[i]["ubicacion"]));
      }
      print('se guardo correctamente');
      return data;
    }

    //respuesta del servidor:
    //{codigo: 1, ruta_user: 1, id_cte: 3, nombre_cte: Prueba 2, tipo: Visita, bonificacion: 2.00, ubicacion: dsv}
  }

}
```

Mi submit del botón:

```
void _submit() async {
  final rutas = await rutaProvider.getRoute();
  return print(rutas);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La table se llama `rutas`

```
CREATE TABLE rutas(
```

Al insertar tienes

```
final resp = await db.insert("Ruta", newRuta.toJson());
```

**Cambia el nombre a uno**

Comment: mil gracias, tenía tiempo con el error y no lo encontraba, leía y leía y no lo podía ver, eso soluciono todo mil gracias.